# C++ deduced size of iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

Apologies if the title is not clear, this is what I am hoping for.

I'm creating a library, where a method accepts an iterator:

```
template<typename T>
void test(T begin, T end)
{
  for(auto it = begin; (it != end); it++)
  {
    for (auto c = it->begin(); c != it->end(); c++)
    {
      std::cout << *c << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

I can print the contents using this method, however, instead of this, I want to do the following:

I want to know the rows / columns based on the iterator.. E.g.

If the values were: `std::vector<std::vector<double>> d = { {1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2} }`
Then it would be a 2x2 vector, so then I could (in the method) size a `std::array` from this. I'm trying to avoid passing through `x/y` to the method, basically.

Is this possible? I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: `std::array` is statically sized, so no.

Comment: `std::array`'s sizes must be known at compile-time. This is not the container you're looking for. Just keep using `vector`?

Comment: @Brian So I could not define the size of a `std::array` by doing `vec.size();`? Darmm

Comment: Exactly, it has to be a constant expression

Comment: @Brian - Ahh! I'm doing some linear algebra type stuff.. I don't really want to use C-style arrays, but, I've been told that vectors are not the right method for this. Any suggestions please? Thanks for the input

Comment: There was a proposal to add `std::dynarray` to C++14, which would have size specified at runtime but couldn't be resized, so like a cross between `std::array` and `std::vector`. It got voted out, though. Anyway, I believe `std::vector` is rarely unsuitable. If you never resize it, it'll be just as fast as an array.

Comment: Seeing as you seem to want a rectangular array, perhaps you should look at [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html).

Comment: @Brian Thanks for the help :) Make it an answer? I'm going to go with this: 1) Use iterators, in the external code they can still use `std::array` and then internally, I'll use an `std::vector` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you did not want to create an std::array but a std::vector you simply can do the following. Maybe I misunderstood your question, but I hope this helps!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

    template<typename T>
vector<T> test(T begin, T end)
{   
    size_t size=0;

    for(auto it = begin; (it != end); it++)
    {   
        size+=it->size();
    }   

    vector<T> ret = vector<T>(size);
    return ret;
}   

int main()
{   
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> d = { {1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2} };

    auto ret=test(d.begin(), d.end());
    cout << "Size of returned vector is " << ret.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And if you do not want to pass iterators, you can make it a bit smaller with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

    template<typename T>
vector<T> test(const T& matrix)
{   
    size_t size=0;

    for( auto it: matrix)
    {   
        size+=it.size();
    }   

    vector<T> ret = vector<T>(size);
    return ret;
}   

int main()
{   
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> d = { {1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2} };

    auto ret=test(d);
    cout << "Size of returned vector is " << ret.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The size of an `std::array` is a template parameter, so it must be known at compile time. What you want to do involves computing the size at runtime, so it can't be done this way.

It is fine to use a `std::vector`. Contrary to popular belief, they are not significantly slower than plain arrays or `std::array`s, provided that you don't resize them after construction (and that you have a halfway decent compiler).

There is a proposed container called `std::dynarray` that is sized at runtime but cannot be resized after construction. However, this was voted out of C++14.